# Url Encoding problem in Java and Solr

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, solr

I am working in Solr and making some filter quires. One of my filter is consists of a space 
for eg:- "fq=listing_type:New home"
But this is giving error. No result is comming out.

I also tried "fq=Listing_type:New+home"
This was not giving error. But no results are comming out. Event there is some xml which have thse values.

Can anyone tell me where is my error?

Here you see the [schema.xml](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7nfYhXS_CxzOTI3NDNlODItZjE1MC00YjViLThjOTItY2Y1NmQ5NzUyM2Q1&hl=en)

Comment: Please append the schema definition for Listing_type, and field definition for its field type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with fq=listing_type:"New home" ??? Why dont you index this field as "NewHome" ?